# How to flatten a template string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, template-strings

In Javascript I want to flatten my template string. So I want this:

```
const str = `
    my name
    is
    frank
`
```

To turn in to this:

```
const str = 'my name is frank'
```

The reason why I am asking is because the massive open spaces with `` is causing errors in GET request URLs, for example:

```
const url = `
    http://0.0.0.0
    :${port}/
    apiCallName?
    var1=${var1}
    var2=${var2}
`
```

Will turn into something massive like:

```
const url = '%20%20%20%20%20%20http://0.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20:80/%20%20%20...'
```

Which breaks the call. I do NOT want to build the string using `' + var1 + '`. I find the template strings read much better, so I would like to keep using them.

NOTE: it shouldn't replace all white spaces. Because sometimes I like writing big strings with spaces in them, like:

```
const str = `
    <label>This is label 1</label>
    <button>This is button 1</button>
`
```

This should not lose the spaces, so NOT this:

```
const str = '<label>Thisislabel1</label><button>Thisisbutton1</button>'
```

Comment: So don't break it in multiple lines...? Or use `.replace()`

Comment: Most IDEs have an option like *Word wrap* or something similar to move the code to next line automatically without adding spaces

Comment: I would not use template literals. Why not `"my name" + " is" + " Frank"` where you can put your line breaks outside the string literals?

Comment: Also, your examples have different behaviour. The first one needs a space between "is" and "Frank", while the second one should not get a space between `http://0.0.0.0` and `:${port}/`...

Comment: Because `\`I can use 'these quotes' and "these quotes" so easily, while also adding any ${myVar} or even doing a quick ${myCounter + 1} or ${runThis().toLowerCase()}\``...and there aren't any +'s to keep track of

Comment: @trincot Yes I agree my examples have different behaviors, but both have been answered for people looking for answers, so I might as well just leave it as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and it's callback function.

```
([ ]+)|(\n)
```

- `([ ]+)` - Matches space character one or more time. ( g1 )
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `(\n+)` - Matches new line character. ( g2 )

```js
const str = `
    my name
    is
    frank
`

const op = str.replace(/([ ]+)|(\n+)/gm,function(match,g1,g2){
  if(g1) return ' '
  else return ''
})

console.log(op.trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to replace all whitespace with the empty string:

```js
const port = 'port';
const var1 = 'var1';
const var2 = 'var2';
const url = `
    http://0.0.0.0
    :${port}/
    apiCallName?
    var1=${var1}
    var2=${var2}
`
const finalUrl = url.replace(/\s+/g, '');
console.log(finalUrl);
```

If the middle of the string may contain spaces (well-formed URLs shouldn't), then only match whitespace at the beginning or end of the line:

```js
const port = 'port';
const var1 = 'var1';
const var2 = 'var2';
const url = `
    http://0.0.0.0
    :${port}/
    apiCall foo bar Name?
    var1=${var1}
    var2=${var2}
`
const finalUrl = url.replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, '');
console.log(finalUrl);
```

Comment: Bhahaha I was busy typing problem with the spaces, which you solved while I was typing it haha. Thank you!

Comment: I am just giving the answer to `Code Maniac` because he/she explained the code nicely. But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = `
        my name
        is
        frank
    `;
    
    console.log(str.replace(/\n+/gi, '').replace(/\s+/gi, ' '));
```